# R - Cut Procedure - Why do breaks and labels produce an error message if at equal length?

Tags: r, debugging, binning

I want to do some binning on a data set:

https://github.com/386er/rdata/blob/master/Chapter3/zipIncome.csv

Here is the code I passed through:

breaks <- seq(2,20, by = 2)

tags <- c("[0-2)","[2-4)", "[4-6)", "[6-8)", "[8-10)", "[10-12)","[12-14)", "[14-16)","[16-18)", "[18-20)")

```
group_tags <- cut(v$MeanEducation, 
                  breaks=breaks, 
                  include.lowest=TRUE, 
                  right=FALSE, 
                  labels=tags)
```

R complains:

```
Error in cut.default(v$MeanEducation, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = TRUE,  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

```
length(breaks)
```

and

```
length(labels)
```

Both return 10

What am I missing?

Comment: You need n-1 labels for n break points.

Comment: And it would not have mattered what the length of the `labels` object in the workspace was because you gave `tags` as the value to be used by the local version of `labels` which you cannot inspect.